# Don't show attachments if they are inserted in post

Tags: attachments

I have attached images that I have inserted into my posts but they also appear in the attachments box at the bottom of the post.

I'd like to know how to make them not appear in the attachments box if I have inserted them in the post.

example post: http://www.fanboybuzz.com/2012/12/sexy-thor-girl-cosplay-2/

I don't want the smaller thumbnail image at the bottom of the post to show up since I've inserted the image in the actual post.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the plugin that is creating those attachment "boxes"? Something called "nrelated"?

Comment: nrelated is what creates the related topics. I'm talking about the thumbnail of the thor girl below that.

Comment: Either this is done using an Attachments plugin (like this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/) and you should look into the plugins'documentation,

Or this is part of your theme file. In such case, you should manually edit the proper theme file to remove or conditionalize that function.

Comment: Can you tell me what the conditional should look like? How do I differentiate between attached images and attached images that are inserted?

Comment: That looks like something your theme is doing. Can you post the PHP for that page? Maybe `index.php`, maybe `single.php`. Your theme doesn't use `body_class` so I can tell for sure.

Comment: I've been editing single.php so it probably looks different from before so you may want to give it another look but my problem is still the same.

Here is single.php

http://www.fanboybuzz.com/single.txt

Comment: So... any ideas anyone?

Comment: All righty then. I guess I'll go for a long walk off of a short pier.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple workaround is: *don't attach the images to the post*.

Upload the images directly in the Media Library: `http://example.com/wp-admin/media-new.php`, go to the post and insert selecting it from "All Media", it won't be shown in the "attachments" list.